# SQL Server SUM based on subsequent records

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3156.0 (X64)

I am not sure of the best way to word this and have tried a few different searches with different combinations of words without success.

I only want to Sum Sequence = 1 when there are Sequence > 1, in the table below the Sequence = 1 lines marked with *. I don't care at all about checking that Sequence 2,3,etc match the same pattern because if they exist at all I need to Sum them.

I have data that looks like this:

```
| Sequence | ID | Num | OtherID |
|----------|----|-----|---------|
|        1 |  1 |  10 |       1 |*
|        2 |  1 |  15 |       1 |
|        3 |  1 |  20 |       1 |
|        1 |  2 |  10 |       1 |*
|        2 |  2 |  15 |       1 |
|        1 |  3 |  10 |       1 |
|        1 |  1 |  40 |       3 |
```

I need to sum the Num column but only when there is more than one sequence. My output would look like this:

```
Sequence    Sum  OtherID
   1         20     1
   2         30     1
   3         20     1
```

I have tried grouping the queries in a bunch of different ways but really by the time I get to the sum, I don't know how to *look ahead* to make sure there are greater than 1 sequences for an ID.

My query at the moment looks something like this:

```
select Sequence, Sum(Num) as [Sum], OtherID 
from tbl 
where ID in (Select ID from tbl where Sequence > 1)
Group by Sequence, OtherID
```

`tbl` is a CTE that I wrapped around my query and it partially works, but is not really the filter I wanted.

If this is something that just shouldn't be done or can't be done then I can handle that, but if it's something I am missing I'd like to fix the query.

**Edit:**

I can't give the full query here but I started with this table/data (to get the above output). The `OtherID` is there because the data has the same ID/Sequence combinations but that `OtherID` helps separate them out so the rows are not identical (multiple questions on a form).

```
Create table #tmpTable (ID int, Sequence int, Num int, OtherID int)  

insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (1, 1, 10, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (1, 2, 15, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (1, 3, 20, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (2, 1, 10, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (2, 2, 15, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (3, 1, 10, 1)  
insert into #tmpTable (ID, Sequence, Num, OtherID) values (1, 1, 40, 3)
```

Comment: `SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version';` will tell you your version, is important information because 2012 have new function can make things easier

Comment: You need to explain what is the logic to generate that output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 
 Here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: You still hasnt explain how get that output :(

Comment: I don't understand. I am trying to get that output. That is the question. I want to sum records but only when there are count(sequences) > 1 but that doesn't seem to work if written that way in the sql.

Comment: Have you read the link I provide about ask a good question? We dont know what are you trying to do, you have to take the time to explain it to someone doesnt know your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will sum over Sequence and OtherID, but only when:
Either

- sequence is greater than 1

or

- there is something else with the same ID and OtherID, but a different sequence.

Query:

```
select Sequence, Sum(Num) as SumNum, OtherID from @tmpTable a
where Sequence > 1 
      or exists (select * from @tmpTable b 
                 where a.ID = b.ID 
                   and a.OtherID = b.OtherID 
                   and b.Sequence <> a.Sequence)
group by Sequence, OtherID;
```

Comment: This helped me get it right. Thank you. Thank you Juan for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to sum by Sequence and OtherID if the Count of ID >1, so you could do something like below:

```
select Sequence, Sum(Num) as [Sum], OtherID 
from tbl 
where ID in (Select ID from tbl where Sequence > 1)
Group by Sequence, OtherID
Having count(id)>1
```